# Custom error message on model validation ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working with ASP.NET Core MVC project, in which we want to set custom message to required field with filed name instead of generic message given by framework.
For that I I have created a custom class as below:

```
public class GenericRequired : ValidationAttribute
{
    public GenericRequired() : base(() => "{0} is required")
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        string str = value as string;
        if (str != null)
        {
            return (str.Trim().Length != 0);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And using that class in a model.

```
[GenericRequired]
[DisplayName("Title")]        
public string Name { get; set; }
```

On view page:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

But message not displaying or validation doesn't work. Is there any other way to  make it work?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]`?

Comment: Thanks! @KirkLarkin I don't want to write *is required* every time, it will take time while changing the text.

Comment: Yes, I thought you might come back with that. Your code works for me, so it must be something else you're missing. But anyway, I'd recommend you create a subclass of the `RequiredAttribute` and don't reinvent the `IsValid` functionality.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Did you check with Core? it works? okay, I will give a try with `RequiredAttribute`

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Do I need to register `GenericRequired` class anywhere? I have checked with another solution, not working :(

Comment: Here to go:[RazorPagesDemo](https://github.com/Divyang16/RazorPagesDemo) customer model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GenericRequired` implementation works only for **server-side** validation. When creating a subclass of `ValidationAttribute`, you will only get server-side validation out of the box. In order to make this work with **client-side** validation, you would need to both implement [`IClientModelValidator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.0#iclientmodelvalidator) and add a jQuery validator (instructions further down the linked page).

As I suggested in the comments, you can instead just subclass `RequiredAttribute` to get what you want, e.g.:

```cs
public class GenericRequired : RequiredAttribute
{
    public GenericRequired()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} is required";
    }
}
```

All this does is change the `ErrorMessage`, leaving both the server-side and client-side validation in tact, which is far simpler for your use case.

Comment: I'm following [this validation sample project](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/validation/sample) for client side validation, however it also work server side :(

Comment: Yes, of course. It implements both server-side and client-side validation, whereas your `GenericRequired` implements server-side only.